# inner control for setting visibility of buttons

Tags: c++, qt, visibility

I want to set the visibility of some buttons automatically. For example, I have some buttons and I want to set them visible or invisible when an action is triggered. I have used an action trigger signal and connected it to a slot to set the buttons visibility base on the triggered action, my code is:

```
void MainWindow::setBtnVisibility(bool toggled)
{
    ui->btn1->setVisible(!toggled);
    ui->btn2->setVisible(!toggled);
}
```

I have many actions so I should write different functions. Is there a better way to connect this function (action trigger and `setvisibility` function) together?

Comment: either make `setBtnVisibility` a slot, and connect it, or use the new c++11 connect syntax. There's no 'better' way to group a bunch of actions with a common trigger than to combine them into a single slot or function. However, my personal preference is to keep individual connections between signals and slots, because inevitably you end up coupling widgets or functions that perhaps shouldn't be in all the different places you want to use your slot.

Comment: thank you very much, I've seen sth like property, if this signal triggered, setvisibility slot called, but i don't know how to use it or it's good for this application?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your comment, are you familiar with how signals and slots work and the `connect` syntax?

Comment: yes i know, but i want to reduce code lines, i want to set some property, when signal triggered, setvisibility of btn, which is defined by QPushButtons itself, called, not 3 line of code for calling my slot and then setvisibility.

Comment: like `connect(myAction, SIGNAL(triggered(bool)), ui->btn1, SLOT(setVisible(bool)));`?

Comment: thanks for your help, but I like to use Q_Property not signal slot